# Gitlab-ci.yml deploy one docker image multiple times

Tags: openshift, gitlab-ci, kafka-consumer-api

I need a way to deploy one Docker Image (essentially one gitlab project) multiple times in openshift.  Where each instance of the deployment is only differentiated by a DataSource (I am building spring Kafka consumer applications that will listen for events and act on individual copies of a database). 
What is the most effective way to do this in both open shift using Gitlab-ci.yml?